# Django - Generic FormView - Passing inputs, into template

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

Using, Django==2.1.7, and python3.7 - I am really struggling using FormView - see below script.

How can I pass variable `search_string` submitted via the form and the value within `context["new_context_entry"]` added via `get_context_data` -  to the success_url, so those values can be rendered in my template on form submission?

```
class ConfigSearchTest(FormView):
    template_name = 'archiver_app/config_view.html'
    form_class = forms.DeviceSearchForm
    success_url = 'archiver/search_results/'



    def form_valid(self,form):
        search_string = form.cleaned_data['search_string']
        return super(ConfigSearchTest,self).form_valid(form)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):          
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)                     
        new_context_entry = "adding additional"
        context["new_context_entry"] = new_context_entry
        return context
```

Comment: I can provide a more complete example later but if you make search string a member variable like so: `self.search_string = ....` then you can override `get_success_url()` to be `return success_url + '?search_string=' + self.search_string`.

Comment: @fiddlestix thanks - if you could provide a more complete example that was be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have done enough to pass something to the template already, you don't *need* to put it in the URL.

**my_template.html**

```
{{ new_context_entry }}  # should render as 'adding additional'
```

If you like, you can also pass URL query parameters to the template.  Test it by typing into your browser URL bar before proceeding further `myurl.com?q=testingtesting`.  Something like this should work (there may be some typos as repl.it is playing up):

**my_views.py**

```py
class ConfigSearchTest(FormView):
    template_name = 'archiver_app/config_view.html'
    form_class = forms.DeviceSearchForm
    success_url = 'archiver/search_results/'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):          
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)                     
        new_context_entry = "adding additional"
        context["new_context_entry"] = new_context_entry
        context["query_params"] = self.request.GET.get("q", "a default") # should be testingtesting
        return context
```

**my_template.html**

```
{{ new_context_entry }}  # should render as 'adding additional'
{{ query_params }}  # should render as 'testingtesting'
```

If you then want to add `?q=testingtesting` to a URL when submit is clicked on your form, you can do some magic in get_success_url:

**my_views.py**

```py
class ConfigSearchTest(FormView):
    template_name = 'archiver_app/config_view.html'
    form_class = forms.DeviceSearchForm
    success_url = 'archiver/search_results/'

    def get_success_url(self):          
        # called automatically after form_valid()
        return self.success_url + '?q=' + self.query_string 

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # called when the form is submitted
        self.query_string = form.cleaned_data['query_string']
        return super(SearchFormView, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):   
        # called whenever the pages is rendered       
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)                     
        new_context_entry = "adding additional"
        context["new_context_entry"] = new_context_entry
        context["query_params"] = self.request.GET.get("q", "a default") # should be testingtesting
        return context
```